# How can I list all the repo URLs that my pip uses to install packages?

Tags: python, pip

The default pip repo is so slow when downloading and installing packages in China. So I added another mirror pip repo to it by creating a pip.ini file and it works. Now I want to know all repo URLs my pip is using when installing packages. How can I list them all?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in one line

```
pip list --format=freeze | cut -d= -f1 | xargs pip show | awk '/^Name/{printf $2} /^Home-page/{print ": "$2}'
```